# what does "if @@trancount > 0 commit tran" mean?

Tags: sql-server, transaction

What does this operation mean please?

```
if @@trancount > 0 commit tran
```

and after that

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
```

or

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

I do not understand the meaning of this sequence of commands even though I searched a lot online.

Comment: have you really searched? I googled @@TRANCOUNT and IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS and the first item at the top of each list is the Microsoft online documentation.

Comment: @DimUser yes, but I not understand the sequence of commands, what is the idea ?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/43256/44324

Answer (score 5):

I think there are two concepts that you need to understand:

1. `IF @@trancount > 0 COMMIT TRANSACTION`

   This checks whether there are still any open transactions from earlier in the
   script, or that will be present if IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS are on. If you don't
   check for open transaction before doing a COMMIT, you will receive the
   following error:

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

2. IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS

   To simplify this, when IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is ON, there is an invisible BEGIN TRANSACTION before specific statements ([see list here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188317%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) if there aren't any transactions open already. And when IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is OFF, your statement is in *autocommit* mode

If you provide us with a code example, we might be able to answer your question more specifically. You can play with this code to see how these commands affect a statement:

```
    /*
    SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON
    SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
    */
    
    
    --BEGIN TRANSACTION  --Uncomment if IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is ON
    
    CREATE TABLE Test (col int)
    
    DROP TABLE Test
    
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
    
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
    
    COMMIT
    
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
    
    COMMIT
    
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
    
    --When IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS is ON, SQL will begin a new transaction count here, 
    --You need to explicitly end the transaction at the end
    CREATE TABLE Test (col int)
    
    DROP TABLE Test
    
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
    
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        COMMIT
    
    SELECT @@TRANCOUNT
```